# How to make Tkinter run in the background or make it handle keypress events outside of the Tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

The idea is that when the user presses the key combination <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd>, Tkinter starts processing keyboard/mouse events regardless of which window is open.

Comment: `tkinter` can't get user events outside its own window. What exactly do you mean by "run in the background" — can't you just switch focus to some other application or desktop manager?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the `keyboard` module it will get the key even if you minimize the window.

Because inside Tkinter using a loop is not a good practice. This is why I use the `root.after` method to make a loop.

```py
from tkinter import *
import keyboard

root = Tk()

def loop():

    if keyboard.is_pressed(hotkey='ctrl+p'):
        print('yes')
    root.after(100,loop) # edited
loop()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that the `keyboard` module is incompatible with the `tkinter` since they both would be trying to handle the same low-level user input events.

Comment: @martineau you are right, But OP wants output even if the Tkinter window is minimized.

Comment: It's unclear that the hotkey in your answer would work it the application was minimized. Have you tested running it that way?

Comment: @martineau Yeah, I test it before posting the answer.

Comment: Works, but not always and with failures.  Windows 10

Comment: @Сергей Check now I change my code.

Comment: Began to issue a whole series of "yes".

Comment: @Сергей I will stick to `100` Because on my side it works.

Comment: The answer may be misleading. Unexplained failures may occur on some equipment. Therefore, I leave -1.

Comment: @Сергей Since `Martineau` say _"I strongly suspect that the keyboard module is incompatible with the tkinter since they both would be trying to handle the same low-level user input events"_ They Both are handle low level user input.